# NodeJS and node-mongodb-native

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

Just getting started with node, and trying to get the mongo driver
to work.  I've got my connection set up, and oddly I can insert things
just fine, however calling find on a collection produces craziness.

```
var db = new mongo.Db('things', new mongo.Server('192.168.2.6',mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT, {}), {});

db.open(function(err, db) {
    db.collection('things', function(err, collection) {
//          collection.insert(row);
        collection.find({}, null, function(err, cursor) {
            cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
                sys.puts(sys.inspect(doc,true));
            });
        });

    });
});
```

If I uncomment the insert and comment out the find, it works a treat.
The inverse unfortunately doesn't hold, I receive this error:

```
        collection.find({}, null, function(err, cursor) {
            ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of null
```

I'm sure I'm doing something silly, but for the life of me I can't
find it...

Comment: I think this means you get an error.
Can you check the 'err' value?

Comment: Also, I think you use when you use 
new mongo.Db('things'...
'things' is DB name not a collection.
I'm not sure that this cause the problem or not

Answer (score 9):

I got the same thing just now. I realized that db.collection is being called over and over again for some reason, so I did something like this (hacking away on your code):

```
    var db = new mongo.Db('things', new mongo.Server('192.168.2.6',mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT, {}), {});

    var Things;    

    db.open(function(err, db) {
        db.collection('things', function(err, collection) {
            Things = Things || collection;    
    });

   var findThings = function() {
       Things.find({}, null, function(err, cursor) {
           cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
               sys.puts(sys.inspect(doc,true));
           });
       });
   }
```

I realize you asked this 9 months ago. Hope this grave diggin still helps someone. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

try to call collection.save() after your insert to flush your row.

take a look at http://www.learnboost.com/mongoose/

"Currently Mongoose only supports manual flushing of data to the server."

Comment: `Mongoose != node-mongodb-native`